# App won't run until update Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I read previous posts but I still cannot solve the problem. I am using API 23 and the app includes a Google Map. The target of the emulator is Google APIs (API level 23). In my gradle file it shows:

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
}
```

In my emulator, I saw the Google Play Services version is "8.1.85" in the setting. I cannot change the play-services version in my gradle file to "8.1.85" and I still cannot figure out how to make the Google Play Service version to 8.3.0 in my emulator.

I'm new to Android so if I miss some information please tell me. The emulator works fine before I add code to make connection with a server and send some JSON abject to the server. I'm not sure if this might influence the Google Play Service.

Here is build.gradle:
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sophie.myapp1"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also faced the same problem.
I used the emulator of Google API version 21 and it is working fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That doesn't make any sense, yet the API 21 emulator does indeed have Play Services 8.3, unlike the API 23 emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Since google is letting this be a single problem affecting MANY developers. I'll carve it out - to fix this I can verify a solution:

in your gradle file:

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+' // this will pull the latest version.

Then in your emulator select an Android Virtual Device, AVD that runs API version 21. I just choose Nexus 5 API 21 x86 - can't remember id it's a default one.

Having said that it's probably important to note that I also have this setting in my gradle file:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.der_geiler.XXX"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```